# Using glmmboot with cluster for logistic regression with fixed effect yields Inf AIC

Tags: r, logistic-regression, glm

I have a dataset with ~ 150,000 observations. I want to run a logistic regression with fixed effect for one of the variables: UserID. I have 10,000 different user IDs, each have at least 2 observations in the data.
I am using  glmmboot in the following manner:

```
     glmmboot(fm, family=binomial(),
                     data=curr.info,
                     cluster=UserID)
```

where fm is a regular formula for the regression.
For some reason, I get an Inf AIC.

I have no NA or one-level factor variables. Even when I put only a single predictor in the formula, which obviously have multiple levels, I get an Inf AIC. What could be the reason for that?

Comment: My guess would be that your data is not playing well with the model you're trying to fit.

Comment: Thanks! What do you mean by "not playing well"? @RomanLuštrik

Comment: Why are you trying to put `UserID` into a model?

Comment: @Phil I was looking for a way to run a logistic regression and control for the users. Each user has some unique charachteristic, and as each user has multiple observations in the data, I want to use the UserID as fixed effect. I found this package and the cluster option seems as a suitable option. Any suggestion for other method to control for UserID would be very much welcome!

Comment: I'm not familiar with `glmmboot`, but I think you're looking for a random effect. Random effect takes into account the 'nature' of a user, where the number of points will be less than there are data points (less degrees of freedom). Not sure if `cluster` does that here. In any case, if you have two points per user, that might be pushing the limit, but I don't really know. Sorry to be of no help.